# How to add multiple services as one object using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection

Tags: c#, dependency-injection

I have service that looks like this

```
public class Dependency1 { }
public class Dependency2 { }

public interface Interface1 { }
public interface Interface2 { }

public class Service : Interface1, Interface2
{
    public Service(Dependency1 dependency1, Dependency2 dependency2)
    {

    }
}
```

The problem is if you add Service as Interface1 and Interface2 you get two different objects.

```
var services = new ServiceCollection();

services.AddSingleton<Dependency1>();
services.AddSingleton<Dependency2>();

services.AddSingleton<Interface1, Service>();
services.AddSingleton<Interface2, Service>();

var factory = new DefaultServiceProviderFactory();
var provider = factory.CreateServiceProvider(services);
var i1 = provider.GetService<Interface1>();
var i2 = provider.GetService<Interface2>();

Console.WriteLine(i1 == i2);
```

I even double-checked this by printing references

```
        unsafe
        {
            TypedReference tr1 = __makeref(i1);
            IntPtr ptr1 = **(IntPtr**)(&tr1);
            Console.WriteLine(ptr1);

            TypedReference tr2 = __makeref(i2);
            IntPtr ptr2 = **(IntPtr**)(&tr2);
            Console.WriteLine(ptr2);
        }
```

I know that you can make two services reference one object:

```
var service = new Service(new Dependency1(), new Dependency2());
services.AddSingleton<Interface1>(service);
services.AddSingleton<Interface2>(service);
```

But in this case you have to create object using contructor but the point of dependency injection is that you don't have to do it manualy. Also there are cases where you can't access some dependencies.

Comment: There's no expectation that the same instance would be returned. You don't need to print pointers either, a call to `Object.ReferenceEquals` would show that the objects are different

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is expected. The registration says what type of object to create when a specific type is requested and what lifecycle to use for that object.  It *doesn't* say that the same object should be returned for multiple types.

If you want to control what gets returned use a factory method for the interfaces:

```
services.AddSingleton<Service>();
services.AddSingleton<Interface1>(svc=>{
    return svc.GetService<Service>();
});
services.AddSingleton<Interface2>(svc=>{
    return svc.GetService<Service>();
});
```

Since `Service` itself is registered as a singleton, the same instance will be returned every time a class requests `Interface1` or `Interface2`

Comment: Best is to use `GetRequiredService<T>` instead of `GetService<T>` in this case. MS.DI would happily inject `null` into a consumer when that registration is accidentally missing.

Comment: Unfortunately MS.DI implementation of IServiceCollection cannot provide services at all. You have to use factory to create IServiceProvider instance in order to get services. And for each provider different objects created. So if you create two services like this:
`var i1 = provider1.GetRequiredService<Interface1>();`,
`var i2 = provider2.GetRequiredService<Interface1>();`
Two objects being created.
So you can't really solve it that way with MS.DI. I'm looking for a way to point ServiceProvider that this services should be the same object.

Comment: @draqula the `services` in lambdas is actually a service provider, not a service collection. It's just a bit unfortunate naming, everything should work.

Comment: @draqula did you actually try the code or just assume it won't work? `Service` is a singleton so no matter how many times you call `GetService<Service>` you'll always get the same instance. The registrations for both interfaces return that singleton instance instead of creating a new one

Comment: Thanks, this turned out to be what I wanted. I was confused at first because of naming.

Comment: `services` is the actual parameter name in [AddSingleton](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.servicecollectionserviceextensions.addsingleton?view=dotnet-plat-ext-8.0#microsoft-extensions-dependencyinjection-servicecollectionserviceextensions-addsingleton(microsoft-extensions-dependencyinjection-iservicecollection-system-type-system-object)). Yes, it's confusing and all too easy to forget there's probably a `builder.Services` or an `IServiceCollection services` parameter in the same context.